# How can I remove a string after a specific character ONLY in a column/field in awk or bash?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with tab-delimited fields (or columns) like this one below:

```
cat abc_table.txt
a   b   c
1   11;qqw  213
2   22  222
3   333;rs2 83838
```

I would like to remove everything after the ";" on only the second field.

I have tried with

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>=1 && sub (/;[*]/,"",$2){print $0}' abc_table.txt
```

but it does not seem to work.
I also tried with sed:

```
 's/;.*//g' abc_table.txt
```

but it erases also the strings in the third field:

```
a   b   c
1   11
2   22  222
3   333
```

The desired output is:

```
a   b   c
1   11  213
2   22  222
3   333 83838
```

If someone could help me, I would be very grateful!

Comment: You used the regexp `/;.*/` in sed but a completely different regexp `/;[*]/` in awk for some reason. If you'd just kept the same regexp in awk as you had in sed it'd have worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to simply correct your regex.

```
awk '{sub(/;.*/,"",$2)} 1' Input_file
```

In case you have Input_file TAB delimited then try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {sub(/;.*/,"",$2)} 1' Input_file
```

***Problem in OP's regex:*** OP's regex `;[*]` is looking for `;` and `*`(literal character) in 2nd field that's why its NOT able to substitute everything after `;` in 2nd field. We need to simply give `;.*` which means grab everything from very first occurrence of `;` till last of 2nd field and then substitute with NULL in 2nd field.

Comment: what does "1" do?

Comment: @gusa10, it is a way of printing current line in `awk`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution using `gnu sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/(^[^\t]*\t+[^;]*);[^\t]*/\1/' file
```

```
a   b   c
1   11  213
2   22  222
3   333 83838
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^\t]*/&\n/2;s/;[^\t]*\n//;s/\n//' file
```

Append a unique marker e.g. newline, to the end of field 2.

Remove everything from the first `;`  which is not a tab to a newline.

Remove the newline if any.

N.B. This method can be extended for selective or all fields e.g. same removal but for the first and third fields:

```
sed 's/[^\t]*/&\n/1;s//&\n/3;s/;[^\t]*\n//g;s/\n//g' file
```